# React 16 State Testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this React.js app that is a simple Cart app. https://codesandbox.io/s/znvk4p70xl

The problem is I am trying to unit test the `state` of the application using `Jest` and `Enzyme` but it does not seem to work. Here is my `Todo.test.js` unit test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Todo from '../components/Todo';

import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

test('Test it', async () => {
  // Render a checkbox with label in the document
  const cart = [
    { name: 'Green', cost: 4 },
    { name: 'Red', cost: 8 },
    { name: 'Blue', cost: 14 }
  ];
  const wrapper = shallow(<Todo cart={cart} />);
  const firstInput = wrapper.find('input').at(0);
  firstInput.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'Pink' } });

  const firstCost = wrapper.find('input').at(1);
  firstCost.simulate('change', { target: { value: 200 } });

  const submitButton = wrapper.find('button').at(0);
  submitButton.simulate('click');

  console.log(wrapper.state());
});
```

The `console.log` at the end says `0`. Which is strange because it *should* be greater than `0` even after `simulating` the click.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding your click code not setting any state, it just 
updates the variable `{totalCost}` where as you should update the state 
in order to get the update state value.

OR

you can test by first updating the state in test class to check whether 
your state updates or not:

```
wrapper.setState({
     totalCost: 20
});
```

Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: I got my variables mixed up. Thank you. But `simulating` a click still does not "add" it to cart.